# reactjs Limit number of checkboxes checked

Tags: html, reactjs

I want to restrict number of checkboxes which can be checked by user to 4.

I found way to do that in jquery, want to figure out how the same behavior can be achieved in reactsjs

http://jsfiddle.net/vVxM2/

```
var limit = 3;
$('input.single-checkbox').on('change', function(evt) {
  if($(this).siblings(':checked').length >= limit) {
     this.checked = false;
 }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this-

Add a `state` on `constructor` to maintain the selectedDataList :

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
       currentData: [],
       limit: 3
    }    
}
```

Bind the function `onChange` on the input :

```
<input 
    type="checkbox" 
    checked={this.state.currentData.indexOf(id)>=0}
    onChange={this.selectData.bind(this,id)} 
    name="select-data"/>
```

on the binded function, do the count :

```
selectData(id, event){
     let isSelected = event.currentTarget.checked;
     if(isSelected){
         if(this.state.currentData.length<this.state.limit){
            this.setState({currentData : [...currentData, id]})
         }
     }
     else{
        this.setState({currentData : 
         this.state.currentData.filter((item)=>id!==item)})
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In short, you have to make the `Checkbox` as controlled component, and store the `checked state` in the components `state` object. Then you can use it to find if more than `n` are checked and prevent other values being changed.

Create a state in the component to store the values

```
this.state = {
  checkState: [false, false, false]
}
```

Or dynamically set the number of values in `checkState` as you require.

Create checkboxes like these with value fetched from the state. Here `i` represents the current checkbox.

```
 <input
   name="isGoing"
   type="checkbox"
   checked={this.state.checkState[i]}
   onChange={this.handleInputChange} />
```

In `handleInputChange` input, check the number of already `true` values in state. If its more than you require, don't update the state. If its less then update the `i`th element in the `checkState` to the value from onChange method.

```
handleInputChange = (val) => {
  // check for the current state values
  // if `canSave` then update using 
  // this.setState()
  // else skip updating state.
}
```